# Error deserializing a floating point number

Tags: python, python-3.x, face-recognition, dlib

I am working with deep learning library for face_recognition, I am having a problem in importing the face_recognition module
this is the output of the terminal when trying to import face_recognition

```
  File "encode_faces.py", line 3, in <module>
    import face_recognition
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/face_recognition/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 17, in <module>
    pose_predictor_68_point = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_68_point_model)
RuntimeError: Error deserializing a floating point number.
   while deserializing a dlib::matrix
   while deserializing object of type std::vector
   while deserializing object of type std::vector
   while deserializing object of type std::vector
```

Please help me out.